# I cannot run Flow type in Sublime Text 3

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, flowtype

I tried installing Flow Type for my Sublime Text 3 on Windows 7.

Issue is:

- Sublime text is installed on partition F:\
- File I want to manipulate with Flow type is on SMB disc - W:\yourplace.sk\assets\send_data.js
- I added also /* @flow */ before content of the javascript

But I get the error

```
[WinError 2] system cannot find the file specified flow type
[cmd: ['flow', 'check', 'W:\\yourplace.sk\\assets\\send_data.js']]
[dir: W:\yourplace.sk\assets]
output of PATH variable is here below.
```

Thank you.

Comment: That error is telling you that the system cannot find the file named `flow` (i.e. the thing you're trying to run). You need to make sure that you add the location of that binary to your system path so that it can be found.

Comment: I added packages directory of my sublime text with flow.py - still no luck 
Also - C:\Users\smarcin\Documents\Sublime Text 3\Data\Installed Packages has been added to the PATH

Output from console
>>> flow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'flow' is not defined

Comment: In your question, something is trying to run an executable named `flow` (not a python script like `flow.py`, if it was, the command would be `python flow.py`). What package are you using to do this? Often a Sublime package interfaces an external application with Sublime, but you still need to install the other half (i.e. just the plugin itself is not always all that is required).

Comment: I am using Package Installer directly in Sublime Text - installing Flow

Comment: What's the name of the package that you're installing?

Comment: Flow for Sublime Text 2 / 3

Comment: The package page lists prerequisites for using the package and the first one is to install flow; did you do that?

Comment: OdatNurd - thanks, I must say that either I am lazy, or complete tutorial for windows is easy to overlook as I spent some time adding flow.exe to some directory where PATH variable is checking for commands.
Solution: I added this flow.exe to one of the folders which is checked by environment PATH, deleted package Flow.sublime from C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User and also Package control cache, restarted Sublime 3 - and now it works and I can run flow with CTRL+Shift+P = Flow, enter ... and it works and checks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OdatNurd - thanks, I must say that either I am lazy, or complete tutorial for windows is easy to overlook as I spent some time adding flow.exe to some directory where PATH variable is checking for commands. Solution: I added this flow.exe to one of the folders which is checked by environment PATH, deleted package Flow.sublime from C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User and also Package control cache, restarted Sublime 3 - and now it works and I can run flow with CTRL+Shift+P = Flow, enter ... and it works and checks :)